# How can I use __DATA__ twice?

Tags: perl, filehandle

How can I use `__DATA__` twice?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    print;
}

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp if $. == 1;
    print scalar reverse;
    print "\n" if eof;
}
```

```
__DATA__
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To use the `DATA` filehandle twice you need to rewind it. The tricky bit is that if you do `seek(DATA, 0, 0)`, it'll be positioned to the first source line, not the line after `__DATA__`. Therefore you need to save the position first:

```
my $data_start = tell DATA; # save the position
print while (<DATA>);
seek DATA, $data_start, 0;  # reposition the filehandle right past __DATA__
print while (<DATA>);
```

See also:

- [`tell`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html)
- [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Data::Handle](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Handle/) module to do the `tell()ing` and `seek()`ing for you behind the scenes.  (Though I believe if you have perl 5.10 or later you can [dup](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) the `DATA` file handle instead of sharing the original `DATA` file handle and seeking back and forth in it.)

Comment: you can dup (or fdopen) DATA in perl's other than 5.10, but it seems like only 5.8.9 ((and possibly other versions between, but not including 5.8.0 and 5.10.0) lets you keep separate pointers per file-handle.  So you still need to seek back and forth on your duped filehandle, or just use Data::Handle.

Answer (score -2):

In all honesty, the easiest solution is to read DATA once and stash it in an array or variable.

```
my @data;
while(<DATA>){
  push @data, $_;
}
```

Comment: Depends. If you do not want to store it, this is not an option.

Comment: Why would you not want to store it? It's already in the script in any event, and if later you want to switch to another source (e.g. an input file), then this approach will make modifying the script much simpler.