# The <DATA> syntax in perl

Tags: perl

Where can I find more about the following syntax in perl?

The connection between `<DATA>` and `__DATA__` is unclear.

```
while (my $date_string = <DATA>) {
  chomp($date_string);
  next if not length $date_string;
  print "$date_string ist Unixtime ",
        $lang_date->str2time($date_string),
        " und ",
    $lang_date->time2str( '%d.%m.%Y %T (%Z)',$lang_date->str2time($date_string) ),
        "\n";
}

__DATA__
1.3.1999
1 Marz 1999
1. Marz 1999
1/3/1999
```

Comment: See official doc http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html and search `__DATA__`

Comment: Fun with `__DATA__` handles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459601/how-can-i-use-data-twice, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10353338/168657

Comment: [Stupid DATA tricks](https://www.perl.com/article/stupid-data-tricks/)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Quoting [the doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/SelfLoader.html#The-__DATA__-token):

> The `__DATA__` token tells the perl compiler that the perl code for
>   compilation is finished.
>
> Everything after the `__DATA__` token **is
>   available for reading via the filehandle `FOOBAR::DATA`**, where `FOOBAR` is
>   the name of the current package when the `__DATA__` token is reached.
>
> This works just the same as `__END__` does in package 'main', but for
>   other modules data after `__END__` is not automatically retrievable,
>   whereas data after `__DATA__` is.

Can add to this only that using `__DATA__` section is quite handy to illustrate some file reading-related concepts in Perl. it's basically a file attached to a code, and contents of this file are easily accessible through `<DATA>`. That's why it's quite popular here on SO. )

Answer (score 6):

Everything after `__DATA__` is treated as a file you can read from the filehandle `DATA`.  `DATA` is opened automatically and you don't have to do anything to get it that way.

What isn't clear?  Your program seems to be using it properly.

Comment: its not my program, its a peace of code I found on the internets and did not understand